# How to match string between two words, and repeat this pattern for all two defined words in the string, Regex?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, mathml

So I want to extract MathML from HTML. For example, I have this string:

`<p>Task:&nbsp;</p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mo>=</mo><mn>5</mn></mrow></math><p>&nbsp;find&nbsp;</p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></math><p>.</p>`

I want to match
`<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mo>=</mo><mn>5</mn></mrow></math>`
and
`<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></math>`

How can I achieve this.
I've tried this expression `/(<math)(.*)(math>)/g` but it matches everything between first `<math` and last `math>` words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the quantifiers are `greedy` in nature, You just need to make it `lazy` by placing `?` after the `*`

```js
const str = `<p>Task:&nbsp;</p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mo>=</mo><mn>5</mn></mrow></math><p>&nbsp;find&nbsp;</p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></math><p>.</p>`;

const regex = /(<math)(.*?)(math>)/g;

const result = str.match(regex);

console.log(result.length);
console.log(result);
```